# Espresso click on specific substring inside a Textview

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I have a layout that contains a textview, shown below that will contain some auto generated links  in a block of text. When the user clicks the links, a window with relevant information is opened up.

[image: screenshot of app]

However, I cannot figure out how to get Espresso to click on the links at all. Have tried many variations of something like

`matches(withText(containsString("45")))`

but this either just doesn't work or makes espresso just click on the textbox itself, which doesn't do anything.

Is there any way to do this? Is it even possible within the limitations of Espresso?

Comment: Did you check my answer? or shall I improve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`openLinkWithText(String linkText)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/action/ViewActions#openlinkwithtext)

> Returns an action that opens a link matching the given link text and uri matchers. The action is performed by invoking the link's onClick method (as opposed to actually issuing a click on the screen).

Here's an example to how to use it :

```
Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers
.withId(R.id.your_text_view_id))
.perform(ViewActions.openLinkWithText("45"));
```

References : [espresso-recipes-for-android](https://medium.com/@dnkilic/espresso-recipes-for-android-afb2466b8137)